# A method is depreciated in framework but cannot apply suggested change

Tags: objective-c, xcode, deprecated, openurl

I'm using a framework that is written in-house and when I try to reduce the amount of warnings I have there is one that comes up constantly, which is 'Implementing depreciated method'. the method in question is openURL

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
```

When I go to the Framework code I can see where it is depreciated and a suggested change

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(nullable NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation NS_DEPRECATED_IOS(4_2, 9_0, "Please use application:openURL:options:") __TVOS_PROHIBITED;
```

The suggestion is to use openURL:options. Looking at the documentation for openURL it says I should use like the following

```
UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
[application openURL:URL options:@{} completionHandler:nil];
```

However, this doesn't work, I cannot separate the parameter openURL from the method as it states above when my method looks like this

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation 
{
..
}
```

How do I implement the new suggested change into my existing method call as above?

Comment: Can you describe, **this doesn't work.**

Comment: I've amended my text above to show my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method that you need to implement is [`application:openURL:options:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623112-application?language=objc) instead of deprecated one [`application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623073-application?language=objc). So replace your method with below one

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey, id> *)options {
    //Your code ..
}
```

**Note :-** The instance method [`openURL:options:completionHandler:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1648685-openurl?language=objc) that you are trying to use is used to open the resource at the specified URL asynchronously.